# yarn - typicode's husky compatibility

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg, prettier

I'm using `husky` for setting git hooks for `prettier` but I am encountering this error whenever I try to commit or push:

```
> husky - Can't find npm in PATH. Skipping precommit script in package.json
```

I'm using `yarn v0.24.5` (which is according to husky's docs is supported) and uninstalled `npm`. Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: probably husky use npm to do some stuff. maybe check husky source code

Answer (score 1):

Husky use npm to run script define in your packages.json

See here: https://github.com/typicode/husky/blob/992e4cb22b6ae0626dc8c12aa0d2fbe5c653bf7d/HOOKS.md

> Husky supports all git hooks (https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks). Simply add the corresponding npm script to your package.json.